# three.js file errors, Cannot find name 'define', Property 'THREE' does not exist on type 'typeof . Property 'set' does not exist on type '{}'.etc

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image] 
I have downloaded the three.js file as I would like to use it but unfortunately the file itself is has errors, does anyone know how I can solve these errors?

Comment: just try to run the project

Comment: have you referenced three.js properly?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not errors in the file. Those are TypeScript type check errors.

Add a `jsconfig.json` file in your project with this in it:

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "three"
    ]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "assets/js/build",
    "assets/js/build-min",
    "assets/js/vendor",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

See here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-autocomplete-with-vs-code/1636/7